# Can a phrase with an -ing come after a comma and another clause with an -ing?

Tags: ing

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> The teenagers drove to the party, some arriving in sports cars, others arriving in limousines.

I'm familiar if the sentence ended after the "some arriving in sports cars" phrase. But, can I place another clause "others...limousines" behind the first phrase after a comma?

Comment: @laurel What do you think? Any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

The sentence *The teenagers drove to the party, some arriving in sports cars, others arriving in limousines* is fine--a nice example of parallel sentence structure.

Both "some" and "others" are pronouns referring to teenagers; you could substitute "and" for the final comma, but the comma separating items in a series (in this case only two items) is effective.  The series could be longer: "some arriving in sports cars, others arriving in limousines, still others arriving in SUVs."